# Pinning memory in .NET the lifetime of an object

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I recently learned that pinning in .NET is no actual process. It's "just" creating a pinned local variable in IL and everything this variable is pointing to is considered pinned by the GC. You can read more about this [here](https://mattwarren.org/2016/10/26/How-does-the-fixed-keyword-work/).

Now I wonder: Is it possible to pin a field of a `class` or `struct` so that the `object` it points to is assumed as pinned by the GC without using `GCHandle` or so. Something like this *(pseudocode!)*:

```cs
public unsafe [class|struct] Something
{
    public byte[] Data = new byte[4096];
    private /*some keywords*/ byte* ptr = /*some keywords like fixed*/ Data;
}
```

If this is not possible within plain C#, is it possible when using IL? Or can't `struct` or `class` fields have the effect of pinning objects? (Maybe it's only possible for local variables?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not as a *field*, no. Essentially, you're absolutely correct here:

> Maybe it's only possible for local variables?

Yes, it is only possible for local variables.

The point here is that the GC does not want to have to crawl the heap to find pins (it is happy to look at the stack - it already needs to do that), and there is no concept of an object *by itself* electing to be pinned.

You can of course use a pinned *local* to achieve this:

```cs
fixed(byte* ptr = obj.Data)
{
    RunYourMainCode(obj);
}
```

but this requires the pinned local to span the code that needs the method to retain pinned.

If you really want something to not move **and you can't use a local**:

- use a `GCHandle` (that's what it is *for*), or
- use unmanaged memory

Note that with `Memory<T>` and `Span<T>`, you can still use *managed* code (i.e. almost zero `unsafe` usage) to talk to *unmanaged* memory. Specifically, a `Memory<T>` can be constructed over unsafe memory, and the `.Span` from that provides `ref T` access to the data (`ref T` is a managed pointer, contrast to `T*` which is an unmanaged pointer; very similar, but managed pointers work with GC and do not require `unsafe`).

Comment: I would jump in here with the sidenote about an upcoming [new *Pinned Heap* and a new `GC.AllocateArray` API](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/PinnedHeap.md) that allows creating already pinned array - kind of thing OP is trying to do.

Comment: "This repository has been archived by the owner on Jan 23, 2023. It is now read-only". The updated link seems to be https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/PinnedHeap.md.

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 5:

```cs
class SoMuchFastArray
{
    static readonly int[] PinnedArray = GC.AllocateArray<int>(20, true);

    unsafe static readonly int* ArrayPtr;

    unsafe static SoMuchFastArray()
    {
        fixed (int* ptr = PinnedArray) { ArrayPtr = ptr; } // leak the pointer
    }

    unsafe int Wow(int index) => ArrayPtr[index];

    int NotSoWow(int index) => PinnedArray[index];
}
```

Obviously, this comes with all the usual disclaimers and health and safety warnings. Make sure you understand the risks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually don't know if I should upvote it now. However, your method names made me laugh.

Comment: You're welcome!  I'll upvote your comment, in any case! :)